# inherit from existing ASPX-Page.

Tags: asp.net, iis

I want to inherit and modify an existing aspx-Page:

- Changes in the existing page must reflect in my new page.
- If possible the existing page should not be modified for this.
- If possible Intellisense in VS 2013 should work.

The existing page is itself a content-page using a master-page.

The following works in IIS, but VisualStudio insists, that it doesn't, which makes think this might not be correct. When the debugger is attached to the new Aspx-Page, it will see the correct members and class from the parent-page.

```
<!-- #include virtual ="SomePage.aspx" -->

<script runat="server" language="C#">
    protected override void MethodFromSomePage()
    {
        base.MethodFromSomePage();
        SetSomeValue("My new Value");
    }
</script>
```

- Is there is better way to do this?
- How do I make Visualstudio recognize the class from the referenced Page?

Injecting a dummy page-definition lets visual studio know the class, but it will not work during runtime (because the would be multiple `<%@Page%>`-Tags). So for now I exchange the `#include` with `<%@ Page Inherits="MyNamespace.ClassFromSomePage" %>` during development, and change it back for debugging/deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on what you want to achieve :

- if you want to have a base class and use the page methods in all pages,using a base class could be the solution
- if you want to reuse markup(and the underlying functionality), I think an user control is a better solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: _if you want to reuse markup(and the underlying functionality),_  this. Can I do this without Changing the existing page? e.g. using the entire Page like a control?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. See this article too : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728784(v=vs.71).aspx